# MATLAB newbie: error using "saveas" to save a plot as a pdf file

Tags: macos, matlab, pdf, printing, save-as

I am a Mac (10.6.8) user.  I have written MATLAB code for plotting calculation results and then saving the plots as pdfs.  I use "saveas" (see example below).

I get this error:

```
??? Error using ==> print at 325
Problem converting PostScript. System returned error: -1.Failed to convert to output format; Ghostscript status: -100.**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.

Error in ==> saveas at 155
        print( h, name, ['-d' dev{i}] )

Error in ==> Results_processor at 1219
saveas(gcf,saveFigTo1, 'pdf')
```

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
calculationResultsPath    = '/Me/Projects/ThisProject';
calculationResultsDirectory          = strcat( calculationResultsPath,'MATLABProcessedResults' );
mkdir( calculationResultsDirectory );

% ...Code for importing results to be plotted from external files (works fine)...

% ...Code for plotting (works fine)... I get the figures I want.

% The problem is:
saveFigTo1    = strcat(resultsDirectory,'/majorsMgO.pdf') 
saveas(gcf,saveFigTo1, 'pdf') 
hold off
pause
clf;
```

Some further information...  This worked fine last week when I first wrote it!  Since then, I think I updated to Mac OS 10.6.8 from 10.6.7, but nothing else has changed in my code or in the version of Matlab I use (R2009a) (unless I have a very bad memory!).

Also, I came across some older suggestions on similar questions to use "print."  I tried using:

print(gcf,'filename').  I did get a pdf, but it would not open in any pdf viewing programme.  I assume (but don't know for sure) that this could be related to the fact that I use a Mac.  I have noticed that there are a few things (especially related to external file manipulation) that don't run on Mac.

If anyone could help, I would be very grateful.

---

Update:
I found a GhostScript for Mac and installed it as Chris suggested.  Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I read on a forum that many Mac users are having problems with MATLAB plots at present, possibly related to java.  There was an operating system update (to OS X 10.6.8) last week and that is when the problems began.  My code worked before then.

I still have not found a solution to this and I don't think the MATLAB people have either, so if anyone has suggestions about how to save plots WITHOUT using `saveas`, I would love to hear them.  The "print" command does not work for me either--it produces PDFs that I can't open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One recommendation I can make is to use a different format that OS X understands and simply convert the result to pdf with a system call

See if the following works:

```
% Load a test image
im = imread('cameraman.tif');

imshow(im); % display the image

saveas(gcf,'test.tif','tif');

% convert to pdf using a syscall to cupsfilter
!cupsfilter test.tif > test.pdf 2> /dev/null

% open the file with your default pdf viewer 
!open test.pdf
```

If the above is not working, yet another approach is to get the bitmap from the figure window and write it using `imwrite`.  *Note*, this method doesn't benefit from the nice font scaling features of the `saveas` and `print`. This approach assumes the `im` variable above still exists.

```
imagesc(im); colormap gray;

% Set the border color to white
set(h,'Color',[1 1 1]);

% Get the image in the figure
frame = getframe(gcf);
imout = frame.cdata;

% on OS X, the stretch window image 
% appears in the bottom right corner 
% of the image.  Remove it. 
imout = imout(10:end-9,10:end-9,:);

% Write the image out to a lossless tif
imwrite(imout,'test.tif','tif','Compression','none')
```

You could then convert the tifs to pdf files as above.  The quality of the figure will depend on the figure size.  In most cases, I wouldn't use this second approach as `saveas` handles the fonts nicely.  *Using getframe is meant only as a workaround to the true problem with saveas*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, ephsmith.  The imshow(im) command produces the image, but the files "test.tif" and "test.pdf" are both empty.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  I'm unable to test on your specific setup.  I'm running 2010a on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Thanks ephsmith.  Saving directly does work, but it is painful because I need to save so many figures!

Comment: I completely understand.  I have to generate loads of figures as well.

Comment: It is interesting that saving from the figure window works. In my version of Matlab, `saveas` is the callback function for saving from the figure window. I'll post another approach that uses `imwrite` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is GhostScript dying and not so much Matlab. A Google for that GS error turns up many [pages](http://www.google.ca/search?q=Ghostscript%20status%3a%20-100.%2a%2a%2a%2a%20Unable%20to%20open%20the%20initial%20device,%20quitting) such as [this](http://technologytales.com/2008/10/06/ghostscript-unable-to-open-the-initial-device-quitting/). Is this at all applicable? If you use GS outside of Matlab does it work?

As an aside, you might take a look at this FEX submission [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629). It has treated me well. Worst case you could output to png and convert to PDF later.

Comment: Thank you, Chris.  I had not even heard of GhostScript until you mentioned it.  I'll look into it!